# How to derive moment of inertia?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, moment-of-inertia

I am currently studying calculus and I am having a hard time understanding this. Here's what written in my textbook:

$$I_{disk}=\int_{0}^{R} r^2 dm=\int_{0}^{R} r^2\sigma2\pi r dr=\int_{0}^{R} r^2\frac{m}{\pi R^2}2\pi r dr=\frac{2m}{R^2}\int_{0}^{R} r^3 dr=\frac{2m}{R^2}[\frac{r^4}{4}]_{0}^{R}=\frac{2m}{R^2}\frac{R^4}{4}=\frac{1}{2}mR^2$$

Can somebody explain why we are integrating with respect to mass? What does σ mean? Where does it appear from?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a small element of the body.The element should be so chosen that the perpendiculars from different points of the element to the given line differ only by infinitesimal amounts.Let its mass be $dm$ and its perpendicular distance from the given line be r.Evaluate the product $r^2dm$ and integrate it over the appropriate limits to cover the whole body.Thus,$I=\int r^2dm$ under proper limits.
We can call $r^2dm$ the moment of inertia of small element.Here since integration of $dm$ is dependent on the radius that if it was just a ring integration of $dm$ would be M which is the mass of the ring.
Here sigma is mass of the ring per unit area $$\frac{M}{Πr^2}$$

Comment: Where sigma is mass per unit area of disk we are integrating it with circumference multiplied by small distance dx which represents approximately small square in area.